# How to use a Controller Action for both Form and JSON requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have a Controller Action that I want to accept:

- either a simple form post with a "name" parameter.
- or a full-blown JSON object that will match against my model.

I have tried annotating the action with [FromForm], [FromBody] respectively like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> PostProject([FromForm] string name="", [FromBody] Project aProject = null)
{
    GenericResponse result = new GenericResponse();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            result = Utils.Helpers.Post(name, "projects");          
        }
        else
        {
            if (aProject!=null){
                //do something else
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.message = ex.Message;
    }

    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

But this isn't matched, it returns a 415 error (wrong media type) when posting the form.

How can I solve this while keeping the SAME route?

Comment: You can use the [Consumes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) attribute to specify what content type is accepted by what action, and have one action for FORM POST and another for JSON POSTs. Have you tried this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no I wasn't aware of that. Care to convert it into an answer so that I can upvote?

Comment: You have to post your ajax too if you want a real help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is way to support such binding out of the box, but currently I can't find/remember it, but you can always process the request manually:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("FormOrJson")] 
public async Task<ActionResult<PostProject>> PostProject()
{
    if (Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        var name = Request.Form["name"];
        // ....
    }
    else
    {
        // resolve the serializer settings from DI if needed
        var aProject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Project>(Request.Body);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or try encapsulating this processing in [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and use something like [`OneOf`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) as incoming type.